# Android NDK sample code for playing .ts file is not working

Tags: android, android-ndk, multimedia

Hi I am using latest Android NDK revision r8d. I am trying to run an sample code given in Android NDK samples ie native-media.The sample code works fine & plays .flv file perfectly but when I try to play .ts format file,the sample app doesn't play it.

As they have said (In README.txt) the sample app can play the .ts file & they have also given an sample .ts file.

But sample app is not able to play that file too.

Basically I want to play .ts file in my app & so far I have not found any working way.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was with ts file.There were some ts files which were working fine & some were not.In project native-media the given sample ts file NativeMedia.ts didn't work in my case.But code worked.